# create div dynamically by passing css id and class to jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have div which needs to be repeated(create dynamically) on  a button click.i have a working code,but it needs to be used many places across pages so i would like to make it a generic one,like i need to pass only particular div id as an input parameter to that method.

```
function textbox_add(id){
  console.log(id)
  var counter = 0;
  $('#'+id).on('click','.newField', function () {
    console.log(counter);
    if(counter >= 3){
      alert("Reached Maximum");
      return false
    }
    var newthing=$('div.addNew:first').clone().find('.newField').removeClass('newField').addClass('remove').val('Remove Field!').end();
    $('#'+id).append(newthing);
    counter++;
  });
  $('#'+id).on('click','.remove', function () {
    if (counter == 0)
    {
      return false
    }
    $(this).parent().remove();
    counter--;

});
}
```

if i use it outside the method it works perfect.The goal is to create 4 text boxes dynamically and if i remove it should remove one by one.

here is my fiddle 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xdsacvdm/)

Issues facing  when i place inside method are:

1. On first click it creates single div on second click it creates two div's then continues for further click's.
2. On clicking remove it works like create.
3. when i click new again it creates the total of removed,created(earlier) all the div's.

I am not able to find where am missing.

Comment: Works perfectly for me! Nice job!

Comment: @abalter can you tell me a solution for my issue :(. am sitting from hours to make it work. Am unable to call the same logic when i place it inside a method.By providing a different id to make it work like the fiddle link.

Comment: Maybe make a fiddle of the "broken" code so we can see how you are using the textbox_add function? @Rathishkumar

Comment: I see now. The fiddle has the code free floating. You want it inside a function. What @JamesSutherland said.

Comment: @abalter i have added my comple code including html in my below comments let me add here too.
 <div class='form-group container1' id ="test">
   <div  class="addNew">
        <input type="text" name="input_1[]" class="input_1" value="Here goes your stuff" />
    <input type="button" class="newField" value="New Field For Stuff" onclick= "textbox_add('#test');"/>
    <br />
    <br />
   </div>
  </div>
and my js as added before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too sure what you are trying to do with the id (I assume it is your div id) that you are adding but you can try replacing your counter with a count of the elements:

```
function textbox_add(id){
  $('#'+id).on('click','.newField', function () {
    if($("#" + id + " > .addNew").length >= 4){
      alert("Reached Maximum");
      return false
    }
    var newthing=$('div.addNew:first').clone().find('.newField').removeClass('newField').addClass('remove').val('Remove Field!').end();
    $('#'+id).append(newthing);
  });
  $('#'+id).on('click','.remove', function () {
    if ($("#" + id + " > .addNew").length == 1)
    {
      return false
    }
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
}
textbox_add('test');
```

[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdsacvdm/10/)

OP basically wants an onclick(html) on the add button, like:

```
function textbox_add(id) {
if ($("#" + id + " > .addNew").length >= 4) {
    alert("Reached Maximum");
    return false;
}
var newthing = $('#'+id+' .addNew:first').clone().find('.newField').removeClass('newField').addClass('remove').val('Remove Field!').attr('onclick','').end();
$('#' + id).append(newthing);
$("#" + id + " > .addNew").on('click', '.remove', function () {
    if ($("#" + id + " > .addNew").length === 1) {
        return false;
    }
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

}
[working codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epZdbb)

Comment: yes you are right it's div id which i will be passing it from html onclick call.For the count of elements you mean to say by counting the text-boxes inside that particular div instead of a counter stuff?

Comment: Yes, if I am not mistaken, you are setting the counter to 0 each time you click the add button.  Also, the counter var will have to be global, and you will need a different counter for each div that you want to add textboxes to

Comment: Yes, if we reset the counter each time then only if we use the same method in another page then it will work if am not wrong.

Comment: You will have to create a new counter for each, else `if(counter >= 3)` and `if (counter == 0)` will give erroneous results.  So if you want to use this code on multiple divs `$(".addNew").length` will change to `$("#" + id + " > .addNew").length`

Comment: i just added the code in the console log the behavior is 
1. First click creates as-usual.
2. Second click it shows 2,3 (creates two div's)

Comment: send me a fiddle link

Comment: when i integrate to my application it behaves as i said but, in the fiddle am unable to call my js method correct me if am wrong (am an intermediate in js and jquery)
http://jsfiddle.net/366y8y2n/

Comment: is it possible to pass the id from html onclick? i tried using but ends up with the same issues again.
As per the fiddle i declare all my function call with parameters(div id's) it works well but, still i have question why its not working when i make a call from html onclien event??

Comment: This is the issue comes up see my edited codepen.http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYMXjg
it takes up the previous div textbox it is not pointing to the current div though i pass the proper div id

Comment: I do not understand what your problem is, it seems to work fine for me

Comment: aah, let me tell you, if you see i have two text boxes one here passing only the id here no somehow it caches the old text box id for the new one too.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYMXjg

Comment: It is because of the `clone`, you do not specify the div, I have updated it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epZdbb)

Comment: yeah thanks i suspect the same i was trying it with passing this,closet may be i maybe wrong .But thanks for the help works perfect!

Comment: if you used this answer, please upvote it and accept it as the answer, then I will update the main answer to what we discussed in the comments

Comment: i did that.And one more query  in the value field if i enter some text in the text box and click new ,at time of  clone triggered instead of placeholder the same value copies to the new text box will can be replaced by a placeholder value instead of text??

Comment: you can access the placeholder with `.attr('placeholder')`, so you will just have to replace the new textboxes value with that

Comment: here it it i tried by using newthing variable and also directly id
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPNWPX

Comment: something like this? [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojxBxE).  Just so you know, doing it this way is not "best practice" at all, there are much easier, and better ways of achieving what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdsacvdm/1/)

You need to pass a wrapper id since you're cloning the `.addNew` content.

Example:

```
<div class="container" id="test">
 <div  class="addNew">
    <input type="text" name="input_1[]" class="input_1" value="Here goes your stuff" />
```

**JS**

```
textbox_add('test');
```

Comment: My Html:
<div class='form-group container1' id ="test">
   <div  class="addNew">
    <input type="button" class="newField" value="New Field For Stuff" onclick= "textbox_add('test');"/>
    <br />
    <br />
   </div>
  </div>
as per your comment that did not help. because as i explained on first click alone works fine.On second click instead of creating another div it create's two div's. Same for remove

Answer (score 0):

Your code was actually working well when you use `id` as selector, but worked wrong (adding multiple times new inputs for example) when you were using `class` as selector (because multiple elements share the same class).

I have edited it so you can use with `id` and `class` selectors:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div  class="addNew">
        <input type="text" name="input_1[]" class="input_1" value="Here goes your stuff" />
            <input type="button" class="newField" value="New Field For Stuff" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div  class="addNew">
        <input type="text" name="input_1[]" class="input_1" value="Here goes your stuff" />
            <input type="button" class="newField" value="New Field For Stuff" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="other_container">
    <div  class="addNew">
        <input type="text" name="input_1[]" class="input_1" value="Here goes your stuff" />
            <input type="button" class="newField" value="New Field For Stuff" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function textbox_add(selector){
    console.log(selector);
    var max_allowed = 3;

    $(selector).on('click','.newField', function () {
        console.log($(this).parents(selector).find(".addNew").length);

        if($(this).parents(selector).find(".addNew").length > max_allowed){
            alert("Reached Maximum");
            return false
        }
        var newthing=$('div.addNew:first').clone().find('.newField').removeClass('newField').addClass('remove').val('Remove Field!').end();
        console.log($(this).parents(selector));
        $(this).parents(selector).append(newthing);
    });
    $(selector).on('click','.remove', function () {
        if (!$(this).parents(selector).find(".addNew").length > 1){
            return false
        }
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
}

textbox_add(".container");
textbox_add("#other_container");
```

And here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdsacvdm/3/).

Comment: if i add it on click method in html this code breaks and its not working.
 <div class='form-group container1' id ="test">
   <div  class="addNew">
        <input type="text" name="input_1[]" class="input_1" value="Here goes your stuff" />
    <input type="button" class="newField" value="New Field For Stuff" onclick= "textbox_add('#test');"/>
    <br />
    <br />
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: That is not how it is supposed to be used. Take a look at the end of the JS. There you define which elements will have this functionality. If you need to add it on the onClick directly to your HTML (I think this is worse) let me know and I can change the code.

Comment: So you say that instead of calling it on click define it in the js itself.right?
If i would like to call it from html means??

Answer (score 0):

I think that this **is not the correct way to approach the problem**, but the OP really wants to do it this way.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="addNew">
        <input type="text" name="input_1[]" class="input_1" value="Here goes your stuff" />
            <input type="button" class="newField" value="New Field For Stuff" onClick="textbox_add(this)" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="addNew">
        <input type="text" name="input_1[]" class="input_1" value="Here goes your stuff" />
            <input type="button" class="newField" value="New Field For Stuff" onClick="textbox_add(this)"/>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function textbox_add(element){
    var max_allowed = 3;

    if($(element).parents(".container").find(".addNew").length > max_allowed){
        alert("Reached Maximum");
        return false
    }
    var newthing = $('div.addNew:first').clone().find('.newField').removeClass('newField').addClass('remove').val('Remove Field!').attr('onclick','textbox_remove(this)').unbind('click').end();

    $(element).parents(".container").append(newthing);

}

function textbox_remove(element){
    if (!$(element).parents(".container").find(".addNew").length > 1){
        return false
    }
    $(element).parent().remove();
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdsacvdm/9/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are trying to do. The main thing I'm not sure of is what you intend to pass in as the `id` parameter. But tell me if this fills the bill.

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/xdsacvdm/12/

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div  class="addNew">
        <input type="text" name="input_1[]" class="input_1" value="Here goes your stuff" />
            <input type="button" class="newField" value="New Field For Stuff" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#createField').on('click', function () {
    //alert('new field clicked');
    var el = createField('some-id', $('#generator').val());
    $('.container').append(el);
});

function createField(id, text) {
    var numFields = $('.container').find('.added').length;
    if (numFields>3)
    {
        alert("Maximum reached");
        return false;
    }

    var $outerDiv = $('<div>').addClass('newOne').addClass('added').attr('id', id);
    var $textBox = $('<input>').attr({'type': 'text','value': text});
    var $button = $('<input>').attr({'type': 'button' , 'value': 'Remove Field!'});
    $outerDiv.append($textBox);
    $outerDiv.append($button).append('<br/>').append('<br/>');

    $button.on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });

    return $outerDiv;
}
```